# Url.PageLink Helper in razor pages

Tags: razor-pages, asp.net-core-6.0

When I set @Url.PageLink("Project") on a page it generates a link like "http://localhost:5236/Project". But when I set the route parameter in the "Project.cshtml" page like:
@page "{id}", link @Url.PageLink("Project") returns "http://localhost:5236/?page=%2FProject".
I can't understand why. How it works?

How to generate a relative path with a parameter that is set in javascript.
Like:
a.href = '@Url.PageLink("Project")'+'/123';

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a parameter to url in js,you can try to use `Url.Page()`:

```
a.href= '@Url.Page("Project")'+'/123';
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to add an id for the link in the js code, when the page is already generated and sent to the client side. The generated link should look like this: http://localhost:5236/Project/123

Comment: If your id parameter is a js variable,you cannot add it into a c# method,such as `@Url.Page,@Url.PageLink`.

Comment: @Url.PageLink("Project") generate a string. For example in page a have code:
<script>
 let a = '@Url.PageLink("/Project")' +'/123';
 console.log(a); // this line print "http://localhost:5236/Project/123" 
</script>
but when i add in Project.cshtml code like this:
@page "{id}"
the script above print - "http://localhost:5236/?page=%2FProject"

Comment: I have updated my answer,with `@page '{id}'`,using '@Url.Page("Project")'+'/123' wiil generate correct url.